# Mongo Look up in java with sum group and conditions

Tags: java, mongodb

I Have 2 mongo DB Collections and i would like join them and that works fine for me using lookup 
but before i do a look up i want to group and sum in one collection with condition

Ex: Collection A
ID,
AMT,
TYPE ( 1, 2)

Collection B
ID ,
TAMT1,
TAMT2,

Now on Collection A 
if(TYPE==1) Then Sum(amt) as TAMT1 if(TYPE==2) Sum(AMT) as TAMT2 group by ID  and then compare with Collection B

Can any one  hint/guide me  how to do it java

Answer (score 0):

We can use Aggregation pipeline operators [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/)
to sum the amount based on the types

Let the collection "a" has the following documents

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59de286a5d9132bd0bf3e870"), "amt" : 100, "type" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59de286a5d9132bd0bf3e871"), "amt" : 200, "type" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59de286a5d9132bd0bf3e872"), "amt" : 1000, "type" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59de286a5d9132bd0bf3e873"), "amt" : 10000, "type" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59de286a5d9132bd0bf3e874"), "amt" : 1000, "type" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59de286a5d9132bd0bf3e875"), "amt" : 5000, "type" : 2 }
```

Mongo Shell query to sum the documents based on types is

```
db.a.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$type", total:{$sum:"$amt"}}}])
```

The result of the above aggregation query on our sample collection is

```
{ "_id" : 2, "total" : 7000 }
{ "_id" : 1, "total" : 10300 }
```

Please note that you have to convert the shell queries to Java Queries